# Can't mount/gave access/assign IP to my Iomega IX2 network server

Tags: networking, server, samba, ubuntu-studio

ifconfig

> enp6s4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
> inet6 fe80::5a35:c75c:b3fe:f4e1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
> ether 00:e0:4a:0a:4a:45  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
> RX packets 715  bytes 104212 (104.2 KB)
> RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
> TX packets 360  bytes 56776 (56.7 KB)
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Within GUI and notification I still got this: when interface tried to connect
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCaap.png) the process is repeated approx. 30 seconds.

I reset the server to the initial settings, hoping to catch the ip, but to no avail.
About 10 years I worked only on archlinux, but I was forced to sit only on windows for the next 8 years, so I forgot a lot. Fortunately, I'm no stranger to it. I never wanted to develop any distro, because it's not a job for me, but only successfully use them. That's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: The title and the content of the question do not seem to match. You may also want to remove the history from the question, it does not help understand what it is you are trying to do. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask